# swift 4 two dpads with spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, multi-touch, d-pad

[A screenshot of my game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfg6q.png)
I want to make a game (with Spritekit) where you can use the left dpad to move the player around in a tile map which already works. With the right one you can aim at opponents which works too. Althought I enabled multiple touch only one controller works at the same time.

Joystick means the same as dpad.

```
    import SpriteKit
    import GameplayKit

    class GameScene: SKScene {

//These are just the touch functions

    //touch functions

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for _ in touches {
            if touches.first!.location(in: cam).x < 0 {
                moveStick.position = touches.first!.location(in: cam)
            }
            if touches.first!.location(in: cam).x > 0 {
                shootStick.position = touches.first!.location(in: cam)
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {     
        for _ in touches {
            if touches.first!.location(in: cam).x < 0 {
                moveStick.moveJoystick(touch: touches.first!)
            }
            if touches.first!.location(in: cam).x > 0 {
                shootStick.waponRotate(touch: touches.first!)
            }
        }
    }

    open override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for _ in touches {
            resetMoveStick()
            resetShootStick()
        }
    }

    open override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for _ in touches {
            resetMoveStick()
            resetShootStick()
        }
    }



    //  update function
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered

        let jSForce = moveStick.velocityVector
        self.player.position = CGPoint(x: self.player.position.x + jSForce.dx,
                                       y: self.player.position.y + jSForce.dy)
        cam.position = player.position

    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `.first`.... Think about what that means

Comment: What is cam? What is moveStick and shootStick? Can you post the code for these things so I can understand what they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As KnightOfDragon pointed out, you are using `.first`. That means your code is looking for the first touch in your scene and then going from there. Your game won't let you use both joysticks at the same time because you won't let them be used at the same time.

These if-statements that you have in your various touch functions:

```
for _ in touches {
    if touches.first!.location(in: cam).x < 0 {
    }
    if touches.first!.location(in: cam).x > 0 {
    }
}
```

Should look like this:

```
for touch in touches {
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    if location.x < 0 {
        moveStick.moveJoystick(touch: location)
    }
    if if location.x > 0 {
        shootStick.waponRotate(touch: location)
    }
}
```

This should fix any errors you have.

Comment: No offense, but some simple questions should not be answered.  Sometimes new developers need to grind their own gears to solve these simple problems.  If we spoon feed these simple questions, they will not develop the critical thinking skills required in programming and will resort to SO to solve every problem.

Comment: ‍♂️ Well, now I know. And knowing is half the battle. I wondered why you hadn't answered this question yet. It seemed simple enough and you are a sprite-kit master.

Comment: Yeah, when it comes to simple ones, I let them spend some time to answer their own questions.  It allows them to learn, and get rep when they do.